# Unable to post questions on Stack Exchange programmers site and its meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

I committed to the beta for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). I can sign in but am unable to a post a question.

I keep getting redirected to the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.

Earlier I posted something on the meta page but am unable now.

Comment: Same for me. Can't search either.

Comment: Me too. Can't post, can't search...

Comment: Thanks, can post questions again.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Looks fixed.  Thanks for the quick response, Jeff (and or whoever else was responsible).  :)

I'm getting this as well.  I propose Hijacking https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-should-the-404-image-be for internal discussion (since we can't post new questions).

It looks like it's been down for a good 8 hours (since that's when the last new question was asked).

Comment: Seconded. I'll post a follow-up there...

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed.  Also, the linked thread has disappeared.  Looks like there relevant people are aware of the situation.

Comment: Excellent! Problem solved. I really like the fact that the SE owners/moderators/people in official capacities really listen to their users!